# Error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, scikit-learn

I am new to python and I am getting an error while executing the below piece of code. Would really appreciate if anybody could help me understand it.
About the data: The dataframe is stored in "train" and the column name is "neighborhood". values in "neighborhood" are like "#Queens#jackson heights" or "#Manhattan#uppereast side". So i am trying to split hashtags and then consider only the first word in each row (i.e. Queens & Manhattan $ etc.)
It does print the expected output but with this error:

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-b199ce84fe1c> in <module>()
      5 for row in train['neighborhood'].str.split('#'):
      6     # if more than a value,
----> 7     if len(row[1]) == 5 :
      8         # Append a num grade
      9         grades.append('1')

IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

```
    train = pd.DataFrame(train, columns = ['id','listing_type','floor','latitude','longitude','price','beds','baths','total_rooms','square_feet','pet_details','neighborhood'])

# Create a list to store the data
grades = [ ]

# For each row in the column,
for row in train['neighborhood'].str.split('#'):
    # if more than a value,
    if row[1] == 'Queens':
        # Append a num grade
        grades.append('1')
    # else, if more than a value,
    elif row[1] == 'Manhattan':
        # Append a letter grade
        grades.append('2')
    # else, if more than a value,
    elif row[1] == 'Bronx':
        # Append a letter grade
        grades.append('3')
    # else, if more than a value,
    elif row[1] == 'Brooklyn':
        # Append a letter grade
        grades.append('4')
    # else, if more than a value,
    else:
        # Append a fail0ing grade
        grades.append('5')
```

Comment: I'm guessing some entries don't have `#`, so you are trying to access a list with only a single element, which would throw an out of range error.  But if you want to consider only the first element you should be using `[0]` anyways.  I could give a much better explanation if you provide some sample data.

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you for ur response.I knew i should be using [0] but it gives me 0s as output. Also, each row in the column starts with a #. This is how the column looks initially: code : `train['neighborhood']`           
`output:0                                #Queens#Jackson Heights#
1                #Manhattan#Upper East Side#Sutton Place#
2                                      #Bronx#West Bronx# `                                                  
& after applying the for loop with split: `output: ['1', '2', '3', ` &so on... (accod. to for loop here, 1= Queens, 2 = Brooklyn &so on)

Comment: @Rucha: Can you show train dataframe (at least 10 lines)?

Comment: @ramesh added an image link in the main question. Thanks.

Comment: @Rucha: Idk why you are checking the length of place names instead of place names.

Comment: @ramesh i tried doing it using names as well.. if printed "grades" gives desired o/p but with the same error hence cannot store it in the dataframe train.. edited the main question.

Comment: No need to split. Just use [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith). I would do something like this
`for row in train['neighborhood']:
  if row.startswith('#Queens'):
       grades.append('1')`

Comment: @ramesh thank you so much for your input. It worked!! Although i was still unable to bring the newly created grades column into my training set, i managed it somehow. Thanks a lot.